# match substring from another list of all possible substrings

Tags: r

I have a long vector of strings containing a market name and other stuff

```
S = c('123_GOLD_534', '531_SILVER_dfds', '93_COPPER_29dad', '452_GOLD_deww')
```

and another vector contains all the possible markets

```
V = c('GOLD','SILVER')
```

How can I extract the market name bit from S? Basically I want to loop over `V` and `S`, replace `S[j]` with `V[i]` if `grepl(V[i], S[j])`.

So the result should look like

```
c('GOLD','SILVER',NA,'GOLD')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `str_extract` from stringr:

```
> library(stringr)
> str_extract(S, paste(V, collapse="|"))
[1] "GOLD"   "SILVER" NA       "GOLD"
```

The `paste(V, collapse="|")` will create a regex like `GOLD|SILVER` and will thus extract `GOLD` or `SILVER`. If the regex does not match, it will just return NA.

Note that if you need to match `GOLD` or `SILVER` only when enclosed with `_` symbols, replace `paste(V, collapse="|")` with `paste0("(?<=_)(?:", paste(V, collapse="|"), ")(?=_)")`:

```
> str_extract(S, paste0("(?<=_)(?:", paste(V, collapse="|"), ")(?=_)"))
[1] "GOLD"   "SILVER" NA       "GOLD"
```

It will create a regex like `(?<=_)(?:GOLD|SILVER)(?=_)` and will only match `GOLD` or `SILVER` if there is a `_` in front (`(?<=_)`, a positive lookbehind) and if there is a `_` after the value (due to the `(?=_)` positive lookahead). Lookaheads do not add matched text to the match (they are *non-consuming*).